# How can I change a UILabel into a number programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I haven't found a clear answer on this question. If it is a duplicate, send the question to me. Here is my problem...

I have a label `resultPercentage`, and programmatically I have been able to change the label if it was a `String()`. How can I do the same, except use an `Int()`?

Here is some example code...

```
var resultLabel = 45
```

`@IBOutlet var resultPercentage: [UILabel]!`

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    resultPercentage.text = resultLabel
}
```

I always get an error. Please help! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `resultPercentage.text = "\(someInt)"` . However.. it seems `resultPercentage` is an ARRAY of UILabel in your declaration.. Are you sure that's correct?

Comment: I edited it, there is a variable which holds the number 45. My question is: how can I put 45 in the UILabel?